# RegEx to get entire JSON string from Javascript within html document

Tags: json, regex

Within the shortcuts app on iOS I want to get the entire JSON object that is passed to the `rwt.remote.MessageProcessor.processMessage()` call.
In the code below I did not include the entire html doc nor the entire json string. The json string is the only json string in the entire document and is always the parameter of the `processMessage()` function (with a space before the `'{'` ). To avoid all misunderstandings, I don't want to parse the objects within the JSON string. I just want to extract the entire json string from the html doc.
Thank you for your support!

```
    <html>
      ...
      <body>
       ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
          if( rwt.runtime.System.getInstance().isSupported() ) {
            rwt.remote.MessageProcessor.processMessage( {"head":...});
          } else {
            var msg='<p style="z-index:100000;background-color:white">' + "Your browser or browser-setup is not supported. <br />Please use one of: IE 9+, Firefox 23+, Safari 6+, Google Chrome 29+ or Opera 15+.<br />Ensure that Javascript is enabled and XMLHttpRequests are allowed." + '</p>';
            document.write( msg );
          }
        </script>
      </body>

</html>
```

Comment: **1** That’s not JSON, it’s a JavaScript object. **2** Don’t parse complex languages with regex.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
rwt\.remote\.MessageProcessor\.processMessage\(\s*(\{.+\})\s*\)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Just need to remove the `rwt.remote.MessageProcessor.processMessage(` part, since its included in the match.

Comment: @tzippy careful, you don't want to match other text within {}. Which language are you using? .NET? Java? PHP? ...

Comment: That I don’t know. Because I’m using the iOS Shortcuts app, previously „workflow“. But I assume that it’s swift.